# Density character of a metric subspaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it true that if $M$ is a metric space and $N$ is a metric subspace of $M$ (I mean, $N\subseteq M$ and the metric defined on $N$ is the same metric on $M$ restricted to $N$) then the density character of $N$ is at most the density character of $M$? By density character of a metric space $K$ I mean $dc(K):=\min \{|D|: D\subseteq_{dense} K\}$. Thanks!

Comment: If by "$D \subseteq_{\text{dense}} K$" you mean "$D$ is a dense subset of $K$", then what you call the _density character_ of $K$ is more commonly called simply the _density_ of $K$, and is denoted $d(K)$.

Comment: Simply take a base of $M$ of size $d(M)$, this generates a base for $N$ of size  at most $d(M)$ and then use choice to get a dense subset of $N$ of size at most $d(M)$.

Comment: @Camilo: be careful. What do you mean by being a base in a general metric space? Be more specific. It is easy to make mistakes in this way not being specific with this kind of vague "notions". How do you use AC in this argument? You have to be more specific.

Comment: A topological base. After you get the base for $N$, you use choice to pick an element of each element of the base, then you get a dense subset of $N$.

Comment: @Arthur: right, by $K\subseteq_{dense} M$ I mean $K$ is a dense subset of $M$.

Comment: @Camilo, it might work if $d(M)\ge \aleph_0$. Good answer!

Comment: @Camilo: Anyway, you must be more careful. If you take $M:=[0,1]$ ($d(M)=\aleph_0$) and $N$ as the Cantor set inside $[0,1]$ (so, $d(N)=2^{\aleph_0}$), it seems to be a counterexample. Your argument seems coherent, but it is still unclear how to get a topological base for $N$ from a topological base from $M$. Which is the mistake in the possible counterexample given above?

Comment: If $\mathscr B$ is a base of $M$, consider $\mathscr B'=\{B\cap N:B\in\mathscr B\}$. Your counterexample is wrong, as any subspace of $\mathbb R$ is second countable and therefore separable(by $\mathsf{AC})$; see theorem 16.2 in Willard's *General Topology*.